# Two different notification settings for one iMessage contact?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

I have a problem with iMessage notifications from some contacts. If I turn off their notifications entirely, I'll miss some important messages. If I leave them on, I'll get bombarded with a dozen notifications every day. This is doubly a problem for some of my closest contacts where I have enabled emergency bypass for them because they gave me listed as their emergency contact.

Only the occasional message actually demands my urgent attention, and I trust the sender to make that decision properly. But it doesn't seem like there is any way to give the sender the ability to specify whether a message is urgent and should create a notification.

Basically, I want a way that friends and family can notify me, independently of messages which are sometimes urgent and sometimes not.

I looked for apps that could do this, but it seems like Apple doesn't let third party apps have permission to punch through the silent/do not disturb settings. The only bypass seems to be for iMessage and phone calls.

Is there any way or workaround that I can use to get notified about some (urgent) messages from my close contacts while suppressing notifications for all the rest?